# Where can i edit the CSS properties of page numbers on BlogEngine main page? (screenshot included)

Tags: blogengine.net, blog-engine

I mean the page links at the bottom of main page. You can see on the image below.

[image]

It seems like it is not within the theme css file. I checked twice.

I wonder from which directory and file i can edit this properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I found out my answer, i will write it down for newcomers so this may help.

I still didn't directly found the source of its css code but in your themes styles folder you should be able to find a PostPager ID. If you overwrite the `li` and `li a` properties of that ID you can customize the design a little bit.

Comment: Also this source may be helpful. It is a little bit old but still remarkable http://www.rtur.net/blog/post/2009/01/25/Post-Pager-Control